# SQL Server stored procedure with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm brand new to SQL Server and trying to write a stored procedure that updates a recordset with the current date/time at the time the stored procedure is called. My code keeps reporting an error near the `=`. The parameter `@SentFax` is the PK of the record needing to be updated, any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FaxMailerSent 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@SentFax int = 0, 
  = 
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
UPDATE FaxMailer 
    SET Done = GetDate()
        WHERE [Fax_ID] = @SentFax; 
END
GO
```

Comment: Take out the comma after the `@SentFax int = 0` and the ` = ` on the next line (before `AS`).

Comment: @ChrisShaffer your the best, thanks! put it in an answer so I can give you the credit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `,`after `@SentFax int = 0` and the `=` between `@SentFax int = 0` and `AS`.

The following should work as expected:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FaxMailerSent 
    @SentFax int = 0
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE FaxMailer 
    SET Done = GetDate()
        WHERE [Fax_ID] = @SentFax; 
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FaxMailerSent 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@SentFax int = 0
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
UPDATE FaxMailer 
    SET Done = GetDate()
        WHERE [Fax_ID] = @SentFax; 
END
GO
```